# nginx redirect or return single location

Tags: nginx, configuration, 301-redirect

I am trying to get `videos.mydomain.com/kickboxing` to redirect to a YouTube link, as well as `videos.mydomain.com/classes` to redirect to a *different* YouTube link. (These are both unlisted playlists, and I want anyone who has access to our website to have this redirect happen automatically for them. This is step 1 of several steps of configuring this and I can't seem to get it to work).

Here's my configuration:

```
server {
  server_name videos.mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/www.mydomain.com;

  listen 80;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/videos.mydomain.com-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/videos.mydomain.com-error.log debug;

  location /classes {
    return 301 https://youtube.com/playlist?list=classes-playlist;
  }

  location /kickboxing {
    return 301 https://youtube.com/playlist?list=kickboxing-playlist;
  }

  return 404;
}
```

I've set this up in my sites-available, as well as enabled it (and of course, set up DNS). Unfortunately, when I navigate to the urls http://videos.mydomain.com/kickboxing or http://videos.mydomain.com/classes, all I get is the 404 url. If I change the `return 404` line to one of the `return 301` lines, then it will redirect appropriately, but *only* for that particular url. It seems to not be correctly identifying the `location` sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you put `return 404;` in the `server` block.

[Rewrites](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) at the `server` level are processed [*before*](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases) rewrites at the `location` level.

To fix the problem, put it in a `location`. (As a general rule you should always process requests in a `location`.)

```
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
```

Comment: Bingo! That was the problem. Thank you so much. I also appreciate the detailed explanation of _why_ this happened. It helps me learn.